# iPhone drawing out of frame question

Tags: view, ios4, drawing

I have an question that base on the performance on my app.

**Some background first:**
I am developing an iPhone application that runs smoothly on my MacBook but a bit laggy on my iPhone 4 dev device. So I started to search for the cause and found it quick.
The application is a game that uses the drawRect method triggered by a timer.

**The problem:**
In this drawRect I am using the drawInRect: method to draw a background from an UIImage. Since I want the background to be moving I have a image that is wider than the iPhone display and I draw this to -400 px by small steps triggered by the timer and then reset it to 0 px to get an "moving effect" in my game.
This seem to make my app to lag. When I draw it inside the frames of the iPhone I have no problems so I am pretty sure that this is the problem.

Are there any solutions for this? Better techneques etc?
I would not like to use an animation of several images to animate the background.

Sincerely yours

Answer (score 0):

How are you moving this image across the screen? Are you triggering a move say every 1/30 seconds because if you aren't this could be the cause of the "laggy" look. I suggest setting up a new NSRunLoop and having this motion be a part of that, and have that run loop trigger every 1/30 seconds so you get a 30 FPS frame rate which will look smooth.

Also, post the code you are using for this and maybe we can spot the problem.

Comment: That is what I have done. I have a CGPoint which holds the origin of the image that I draw. I decline this every 1/30 of a second until it reaches -400 px and then I reset it to 0 px. Everytime that I update the CGPoint I draw a CGRect which I pass to the drawRect method.
The lag only appear when drawing outside the bounds. Lets say if I decline to 100 px (positive) by small steps and reset to 200 px I do not get any performance problems.

Comment: EDIT: It may also have to do with the size of the image drawn. It is now 960 by 320 pixels. Are there any techneques for large .png files or should I comprimize it?

Answer (score 0):

I was just re-reding this question and I thought of a solution for this. Instead of redrawing it every 1/30 of a second, why don't you just draw it once and redefine the frame that the image sits in. Create a method that does this and then set a new nstimer that calls this new method every 1/30 of a second. Something like this

```
-(void) movePicture {
    position += 5;
    if (position <= 0) {
        [moveTimer invalidate];
    }
    picture.frame = CGRectMake(position,10,10,10);
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Either that it you could just use an animation and set it to run for whatever amount of time that you want. This will end up happening asynchronously so you should not have to worry about it lagging the application much if at all.